# How could I rescan for strings to prevent infinite while loop?

Tags: c

The code is meant to receive two strings with a comma somewhere in between them. But the problem I keep running into is that after the first input such as, "Jill, Allen", it reiterates using that input until I get an error. The variable 'fullInpt' was an array first and I changed it into a const in order to test by manually changing it to "q" so that the program would stop. Also, the line that prints 'fullInpt' is also meant to test by checking what it had stored after I would try changing it through either input or in the code. I'm running it in zybooks, but I tested it on the Code::blocks IDE and to make sure the problem persisted even there.

Other possible inputs could include:
'Jill , Allen'
'Jill,Allen'
'Jill Allen'

I don't seem to have a problem when it comes to parsing the strings, it is mainly with scanning for new input. But I welcome any form of advice as C is still new to me. Thank you in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) {
   const int USER_TEXT_LIMIT = 100;
   char fullInpt[USER_TEXT_LIMIT];
   char str1[20];
   char str2[20];
   bool inputDone;

   while(!inputDone) {
      
      printf("Enter input string:\n");
      fgets(fullInpt, USER_TEXT_LIMIT, stdin);
      printf("%s", fullInpt);
      
      if(strcmp(fullInpt, "q") == 0) {
         inputDone = true;   
      }
      else if(strchr(fullInpt, ',') == NULL) {
         printf("Error: No comma in string.\n");
         printf("\n");
      }
      else {
         
         sscanf(fullInpt, "%20[^,] , %20s", str1, str2);
         printf("First word: %s\n", str1);
         printf("Second word: %s\n", str2);
         printf("\n");
      }
      
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `'fullInpt' was an array first and I changed it into a const` That was a very bad idea. It is now an unintialised pointer. Writing/scanning to an unintialised (ie garbage) pointer is Undefined Behaviour. Suggest you change it back.

Comment: @turi_hdez The variable   inputDone ia not initialized bool inputDone; So the while loop 

   while(!inputDone) { has undefined behavior

Comment: @turi_hdez The format string scanf("%[^\n]s", fullInpt); is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

The pointer `fullInpt` is uninitialized and has the qualifier `const`

```
char const *fullInpt;
```

So this call of scanf

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", fullInpt);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Moreover the format string `"%[^\n]s"` is incorrect.

The variable `inputDone` is also uninitialized.

```
bool inputDone;
```

So the while loop

```
while(!inputDone) {
```

again invokes undefined behavior.

The program can look for example the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 20 }; 
    char fullInpt[2 * N];
    char str1[N];
    char str2[N];
   
    bool inputDone = false;

    do
    {
        printf( "Enter input string: " );
        scanf( " %39[^\n]", fullInpt );
        printf( "%s\n", fullInpt );
      
        if ( strcmp( fullInpt, "q") == 0 ) 
        {
            inputDone = true;   
        }
        else if ( strchr( fullInpt, ',' ) == NULL ) 
        {
            printf( "Error: No comma in string.\n");
            printf("\n\n");
        }
        else 
        {
            sscanf( fullInpt, "%19[^,] , %19s", str1, str2 );
            printf( "First word: %s\n", str1 );
            printf( "Second word: %s\n", str2 );
            printf("\n\n");
        }
    } while ( !inputDone )

    return 0;
}
```

The code can be more safer if to use variable length arrays. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 40 }; 
    char fullInpt[N];
   
    bool inputDone = false;

    do
    {
        printf( "Enter input string: " );
        scanf( " %39[^\n]", fullInpt );
        printf( "%s\n", fullInpt );
      
        if ( strcmp( fullInpt, "q") == 0 ) 
        {
            inputDone = true;   
        }
        else 
        {
            char *p = strchr( fullInpt, ',' );
           
            if ( p == NULL ) 
            {
                printf( "Error: No comma in string.\n");
                printf("\n\n");
            }
            else 
            {
                char str1[p - fullInpt + 1];
                char str2[strlen( p + 1 ) + 1];

                sscanf( fullInpt, "%[^,] , %s", str1, str2 );

                printf( "First word: %s\n", str1 );
                printf( "Second word: %s\n", str2 );
                printf("\n\n");
            }
        }
    } while ( !inputDone )

    return 0;
}
```

Pay attention to that though the entered string can contain a comma nevertheless the second word can be empty. You should also add such a check whether the second word is empty.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The original code was changed after my answer. Initially there was a call of scanf.

Comment: Yes, on deeper review your original post was ~5 minutes before OP's change to `fgets()`.